# unable to provide http access for analysis services?

Tags: ssas, iis-8

[image]

I have installed analysis service in my local system, In IIS i have created application pool under default website and created application called OLAP that points to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OLAP` , When i try to connect using `http://localhost/OLAP/msmdpump.dll` in SSMS, i get the following error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it.

[image]

How should i solve this? Should i add anything on the database side?

[image]

Comment: There's more steps than just creating an Application Pool and Application. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I have followed all the steps from the same article and still not able to connect from ssms, I have also enabled windows authentication in iis @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: What is the site binding then? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background

Comment: please refer to the image added above @LexLi

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem is in configuring the handler mappings.  They should look like this:

[image]

And to test, use wget in Powershell.  If you get a soap response, the ISAPI extension is properly configured.:

```
PS C:\Users\dbrowne> wget http://localhost/olap/msmdpump.dll -UseDefaultCredentials
wget : <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault xmlns="http://schem
as.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><faultcode>XMLAnalysisError.0xc10e0002</faultcode><faultstring>Parser: The syntax for
'GET' is incorrect.</faultstring><detail><Error ErrorCode="3238920194" Description="Parser: The syntax for 'GET' is
incorrect." Source="Unknown" HelpFile=""/></detail></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
At line:1 char:1
+ wget http://localhost/olap/msmdpump.dll
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: handler should point to wwwroot - olap- msdpump.dll right? @David Browne - MIcrosoft

Comment: It should point to the file system location of the dll.  If you copied it to a folder under wewroot then, yes, else no.  I installed the data pump on my SSAS box, so pointed the handler to the location in the SSAS bin folder.

Comment: i have copied and pasted into wwwroot, i still face the issue? Do i need to add  anything on the database side or in iis? @David Browne - Microsoft

Comment: And when you test in powershell?

Comment: please check the image attached @David Browne - Microsoft

Comment: Verify that Windows Auth is installed and enabled on the site, and add the `-UseDefaultCredentials` switch to your testing with `wget`.

Comment: windows auth is enabled

Comment: should sql server ,analysis service be local system or network service or local service? @David Browne - Microsoft